# Should a SKU be associated to warehouse or supply table?

Tags: postgresql, database-design

This may be a trivial question for any of you experienced in supply chain models. The model I am building in PosgreSQL has 3 tables:

```sql
create table supply (
  id       serial primary key,
  barcode  varchar,
  title    varchar
  ...
);

create table warehouse (
  id     serial primary key,
  title  varchar,
  ...
);

create table warehouse_supply (
  id            serial primary key,
  warehouse_id  bigint not null,
  supply_id     bigint not null,
  ...
  foreign key (supply_id) references supply (id),
  foreign key (warehouse_id) references warehouse (id)
);
```

I was tempted to include an `SKU` (Stock Keeping Unit) column at table `supply`, but the very definition of SKU made me think it is a warehouse right to state their own SKU naming policy (this could occur with 3rd party warehouses).

Am I right? Should I include an `sku varchar` column at `warehouse_supply` instead of `supply`?

Comment: Including third party warehouses could lead to such a situation, specially with big ones. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mention that `SKU` could vary by `Warehouse`, the best solution would be to store the default or in-house `SKU` with `Supply` and create an optional column to denote when a particular `Warehouse` uses a different value.

I'd also drop the `Id` as they will not guarantee uniqueness, force you to use more joins, and generally clog up the data model.  Use them sparingly and only if the key is very large (in bytes) or some duplication is allowed by design.

Declare your constraints so any error messages make sense.  Don't name things `Id` as context matters.

It makes the most sense to define the custom SKUs in their own tables as:

1. It must be unique and you cannot declare a unique constraint on a NULLable column.
2. The number of items with custom SKUs will probably be small and the table will function like a filtered index for queries.

```
CREATE TABLE Supply 
(
  SKU      varchar(14)   NOT NULL,  --If SKUs are used, they will be the primary method of searching for inventory and should be the primary key
  BarCode  varchar(14)   NOT NULL,  --GTIN has max length of 14
  Title    varchar(50)   NOT NULL,  --Name?  Description?
  CONSTRAINT PK_Supply PRIMARY KEY (SKU),
  CONSTRAINT AK_Supply UNIQUE (BarCode)
);

CREATE TABLE Warehouse 
(
  WarehouseId  serial       NOT NULL,
  Title        varchar(50)  NOT NULL,  --Name?
  CONSTRAINT PK_Warehouse PRIMARY KEY (WarehouseId),
  CONSTRAINT AK_Warehouse UNIQUE (Title)
);

CREATE TABLE WarehouseSupply 
(
  WarehouseId  int          NOT NULL,
  SKU          VARCHAR(14)  NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT FK_WarehouseSupply_Stores_Supply FOREIGN KEY (SKU) REFERENCES Supply (SKU),
  CONSTRAINT FK_WarehouseSupply_Stored_IN_Warehouse FOREIGN KEY (WarehouseId) REFERENCES Warehouse (WarehouseId),
  CONSTRAINT PK_WarehouseSupply PRIMARY KEY (WarehouseId, SKU)
);

CREATE TABLE WarehouseSupplyCustomSKU
(
  WarehouseId  int          NOT NULL,
  SKU          VARCHAR(14)  NOT NULL,
  CustomSKU    VARCHAR(14)  NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT FK_WarehouseSupplyCustomSKU_Belongs_To_WarehouseSupply FOREIGN KEY (WarehouseId, SKU) REFERENCES WarehouseSupply (WarehouseId, SKU),
  CONSTRAINT PK_WarehouseSupplyCustomSKU PRIMARY KEY (WarehouseId, SKU),
  CONSTRAINT AK_WarehouseSupplyCustomSKU UNIQUE (WarehouseId, CustomSKU)
)
;
```

Comment: Thank you @bbaird. This was a simplified case to focus in the SKU issue but yes, I tend not to name constraints in PostgreSQL, as the names it generates by default are very descriptive.

Answer (score 1):

If the SKU is an attribute of a supply entity being located at a warehouse, then I would agree with your assessment to put it in the warehouse_supply table.

OTOH, if the company has decided that SKUs are the same regardless of the location, then it is an attribute of supply.